# Should I destandardize the errors from training the neural network?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, gradient-descent, feature-engineering

So, I am learning a bit about Neural Networks. I have built a code in PyTorch for regression, and I have standardized both the features and the target variables following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re) answer. My question is that should I destandardize the loss value before plotting the elbow curve to observe the train and validation errors across the epochs. I destandardize the predictions on the test dataset to make some plots. But is that necessary for the [elbow curve](https://www.google.com/search?q=train%20and%20validaton%20plot%20deep%20learning&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjL2uj_37D9AhUMuyoKHY9KCrgQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=train%20and%20validaton%20plot%20deep%20learning&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoGCAAQBxAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAgQHjoHCAAQgAQQGFDbE1jkM2CkNWgAcAB4AIABR4gB6wySAQIyNpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=RQn6Y4ukJIz2qgGPlanACw&bih=1057&biw=1920#imgrc=9PUHo9ZiITcFAM) as well? Adding code to make my question a bit more understandable, I guess??

```
...
x_train = StandardScale(x_train, x_scaler) # Just indicating that scaling is done here
y_train = StandardScale(y_train, y_scaler)
... #Similarly for validation and test datasets ...
dl = DataLoader(params) #for all train, test, val
model = net(params)
optimizer = SGD(model.params(), other-params)

for epoch in range(0, num_epochs):
    
    for i, (x_train, y_train) in enumerate(dl): # This loop is run for both train and val at each epoch.
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x_train)
        loss = criterion(output, y_train)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
    ...
    ...
    ...
    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dl)
    
    history[phase].append(epoch_loss) #history is a dictionary containing training and validation phase losses

fig = plt.figure() #Plotting the elbow plot
plt.plot(history["train"])
plt.plot(history["val"])

y_pred = model(x_test)
y_pred = StandardScaler.inverse_transform(y_pred) # This step is not done for the elbow plot and that is my question.

fig1 = plt.figure() # Plotting the performance on test data
plt.plot(y_pred)
plt.plot(y_test)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you look at both pictures? How different do they look?

Comment: @Dave Thank you for taking the time to reply. 

The scale is what's different. The target is in the range [0, 1] and the train and validation error is in the range of 0.3xx once destandardized. But it performs well on the test dataset, where the error is in the range of 0.04x. When I say Error, I mean RMSE. Is it possible that I am interpreting the elbow curve wrong?